# Upload and download big files into PostgreSQL without consuming a lot RAM

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I managed to successfully upload and download files using this Java code:

**Upload**

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE_FILES (ID, DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE_ID, FILE_NAME, FILE) "
                    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                ps.setInt(1, obj.number);
                ps.setInt(2, obj.number);
                ps.setString(3, file.getSubmittedFileName());

                InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
                ps.setBinaryStream(4, inputStream, inputStream.available());

                ps.executeUpdate();
```

**Download**

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT *, OCTET_LENGTH(FILE) AS FILE_LENGTH FROM DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE_FILES WHERE DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE_ID = ?");

            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
            {
                String file_name = rs.getString("FILE_NAME");
                .........

                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                try (InputStream input = rs.getBinaryStream("FILE");
                    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream())
                {
                    int numRead = 0;

                    while ((numRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    }
                }
```

But when I tried to use it for 2GB files I get exception for memory size. Unfortunately the file is stored in RAM during insert/select.

Is there another approach to this solution without consuming too much RAM memory?

Comment: What is the data type of  the column `file`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name currently it's BYTEA, but I can change it if you recommend.

Comment: A `bytea` column has a maximum length of 1GB

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, what column type can you recommend for fixing the above issue?

Comment: you will have to use [large objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) but they are quite complicated to work with: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/binary-data.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, what will be the impact of the RAM consumption during upload/download?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the local filesystem for a file you could stream and just the file information in your Database? 2GB Files in a Database are a bad idea, so what are you try to accomplish by bloating the Tablespace? Just select the filename and start a Streamreader/Streamwriter.

Comment: That would require the Java program to run on the database server - something that is not usually the case

Comment: Yes you are right about Java Programs on an db server. But that is the reason cdn servers where invented, just give an link back and http 301 to the cdn link. Just a thought, it is uncommon to store blobs that big to a database, backup it alone would be hell at some point.